# RubyGems.org cannot process this gem

Tags: rubygems

I was trying to upload a gem to Rubygems, but it throws this error:

```
$ gem push voxel4r.gemspec -V
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
POST https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems
422 Unprocessable Entity
RubyGems.org cannot process this gem.
Please try rebuilding it and installing it locally to make sure it's valid.
```

It was sucessfully built:

```
$ gem build voxel4r.gemspec 
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: voxel4r
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: voxel4r-0.0.1.gem
```

I have a Rubygems account and I have my `~/.gem/credentials` file.
What else can I do?

Answer (score 4):

I did a mistake:

I tried to push gemspec file instead of gem file.

```
$ gem push voxel4r-0.0.1.gem -V
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
POST https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems
200 OK
Successfully registered gem: voxel4r (0.0.1)
```